# Make MQTT client connection to be always present

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, sming

I am using ESP8266 chip and the SMING software framework `MqttClient_Hello` example.

I want the MQTT connection to always be present at all time. If for whatever reason the connection is broken, I would like a reconnection to take place. How can this be done?

The relevant code in `MqttClient_Hello`;

```
void startMqttClient();
void onMessageReceived(String topic, String message);
MqttClient mqtt("192.168.1.8", 1883, onMessageReceived);

// Run MQTT client
void startMqttClient()
{
   mqtt.connect("esp8266");
   mqtt.subscribe("TopicTest");
}
```

What needs to be changed in the code to ensure constant connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So SMING does not seem to have a disconnect or error callback.
`int mqtt_ping(mqtt_broker_handle_t* broker){...}` is implemented in `libemqtt` and you could try to maintain the connection with a regular ping and try to reconnect if it fails.